# Как возвращать массивы в операторе switch-case в языке Java?

Tags: java, массивы, строки, switch, return

Всем привет!
Суть задачи:нужно реализовать публичный статический метод,который возвращает массив из двух элементов – названий выходных дней на английском. Метод принимает на вход параметр – формат возврата в виде строки. Всего существует два возможных значения:

```
"long" (по умолчанию) – массив содержит строки "saturday" и "sunday"
"short" – массив содержит строки "sat" и "sun"
```

Задачу нужно решать с использованием оператора switch-case
Мое решение выглядит следующим образом:

```
class App {
   
  public static void main(String[] args){
      App.getWeekends("long");
  }

    public static void getWeekends(){


     String[] day =new String[4];
     day[0]="saturday";
     day[1]="sunday";
     day[2]="sat";
     day[3]="sun";

     switch(day){
        case "long":
          return {"saturday","sunday"};

        case "short":
          return {"sat", "sun"};

      default:
       return null;    
     }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Так, и в чём, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: Не могу найти ошибку

Comment: @PeteAlexandrovich Какую ошибку? В чем она заключается?

Comment: как минимум в getWeekends ты ничего не передаёшь, а вся пляска с `String[] day....` вообще не нужна

Comment: `void` getWeekends - неправильно, т.к. ты должен вернуть массив......... return null; - неправильно по той же причине

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста,как лучше вернуть массив из двух элементов через switch-case?

Comment: Как мне лучше переписать этот код,на ваш взгляд?

Comment: @PeteAlexandrovich Компилировать _свой_ код пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал через https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler-ide/


MyClass.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
          return {"saturday","sunday"};

6 errors

Comment: Используйте классы

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static String[] getWeekends(String day) {
    switch(day) {
        case "long":
            return new String[]{"saturday", "sunday"};
        case "short":
            return new String[]{"sat", "sun"};
        default:
            return null;    
    }
}
```

или в ещё более кратком виде с использованием синтаксиса [`switch expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html), который поддерживается полностью в Java 14 и выше:

```java
public static String[] getWeekends(String day) {
    return switch(day) {
        case "long" -> new String[]{"saturday", "sunday"};
        case "short" -> new String[]{"sat", "sun"};
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown day format: " + day);    
    };
}
```

*Примечание*: Вместо возврата `null` лучше выбросить исключение о неправильном входном параметре.